# convert date from gergorian to shamsi

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have loaded dates in my code . At this time I cant change my code I mean I will do it when there is any other solution.
so would you pleas tell me how can I convert dates to shamsi format?
is there any function to for converting date to shamsi format in js??

may codes:

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number"><input type="button" value="load" id="btn">
<select id="date" name="date">

</select>
```

js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var n=$("#number").val();
            var i;
            var d = new Date();
            for (i=1 ; i<=n ;i++){
//              var b=n;
                $("#date").append("<option>"+d.getFullYear()+"/"+d.getMonth()+"/"+(d.getDate()+i)+"</option>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850436/how-do-you-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-jalali-shamsi-persian-format

Comment: i think what your searching is in the link above.

Comment: thank you so much.It worked well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a Unix timestamp to Jalali/Shamsi/Persian format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850436/how-do-you-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-jalali-shamsi-persian-format)

Answer (score 2):

To convert the Gregorian date to jalali in JavaScript you can do the following.

The first method:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fa-IR").format(new Date());
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fa-IR").format('2022/01/31');
```

The second method:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');
```

I changed your code, you can test.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var n=$("#number").val();
        var i;
        const formatOptions = {numberingSystem: 'latn', hourCycle: 'h24', hour12: false};
        var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR', formatOptions);
        var d = date.split('/');
        for (i=1 ; i<=n ;i++){
            $("#date").append("<option>"+d[0]+"/"+d[1]+"/"+(+d[2]+i)+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="number" name="number"><input type="button" value="load" id="btn">
<select id="date" name="date"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shamsi seems to be an exotic calendar format which is not directly supported by JavaScript.

You could take a look at Moment.js and [this additional library, `moment-jalaali`](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) for Moment.js (YMMV: haven't tried this).

Comment: Jalaali/shamsi are the same just have to provide the format