# how to convert linux timestamp to persian/jalali in react native?

Tags: datetime, react-native, jalali-calendar

I want to convert linux timestamp like (1538522020) to jalali/shamsi date time like (11/7/1397). how can I convert these times to each other?

Comment: have you see https://momentjs.com/ ? this might help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a Unix timestamp to Jalali/Shamsi/Persian format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850436/how-do-you-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-jalali-shamsi-persian-format)

Comment: @DacreDenny yea that definitely helped me thanks for the answer

Comment: I've found and used an useful package `https://github.com/webilix/jalali-date-time#readme` that can convert UTC time and date to Persian and other locale.

Answer (score 2):

I used https://github.com/jalaali/jalaali-js
and it worked like a charm

```
npm install --save jalaali-js
```

In your code:

```
var jalaali = require('jalaali-js')
jalaali.toJalaali(new Date(JS Date Object which could be a timestamp))
```

Answer (score 1):

finaly I have found the answer, just used:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-jalaali package to convert it to jalali/persian date in render method:

import jMoment from 'moment-jalaali-react-native-calendar';

and in render method:
const jdatetime = jMoment.unix(time).format('d jMMMM jYYYY');

Answer (score 0):

No need to install a module. Use this pure javascript code:
(The performance and speed are much better)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071513/16212595